# R- Convert column of lists into different columns using their values as names (dummy)

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a table containing data of movies, and in the last column, it has the categories the movie belongs to.

```
  movieId                              title                   category
       1                   Toy Story (1995)  Animation|Children|Comedy
       2                     Jumanji (1995) Adventure|Children|Fantasy
       3            Grumpier Old Men (1995)             Comedy|Romance
       4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)               Comedy|Drama
       5 Father of the Bride Part II (1995)                     Comedy
       6                        Heat (1995)      Action|Crime|Thriller
```

I want to create one column for each category and put 1 if it was written in the list for that movie and zero if not.
Something like:

```
movieId title   animation   comedy  drama
1        xx        1           0      1
2        xy        1           0      0
3        yy        1           1      0
```

So far, I have only converted the string to a list with:

```
f<-function(x) {strsplit(x, split='|', fixed=TRUE)}
movies2$m<-lapply(movies2$category, f)
```

But I don't know how to do the rest.

I was thinking of Python dictionaries. But I don't know how to do this in R.

Data

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  text = " movieId                              title                   category
                  1                   'Toy Story (1995)'  Animation|Children|Comedy
                  2                     'Jumanji (1995)' Adventure|Children|Fantasy
                  3            'Grumpier Old Men (1995)'             Comedy|Romance
                  4           'Waiting to Exhale (1995)'               Comedy|Drama
                  5 'Father of the Bride Part II (1995)'                     Comedy
                  6                        'Heat (1995)'      Action|Crime|Thriller")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[-3],mtabulate(strsplit(df1$category, "[|]")))
# movieId                              title Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Drama Fantasy Romance Thriller
#1       1                   Toy Story (1995)      0         0         1        1      1     0     0       0       0        0
#2       2                     Jumanji (1995)      0         1         0        1      0     0     0       1       0        0
#3       3            Grumpier Old Men (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       1        0
#4       4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     1       0       0        0
#5       5 Father of the Bride Part II (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       0        0
#6       6                        Heat (1995)      1         0         0        0      0     1     0       0       0        1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(df1[-3], as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$category,
                           "[|]"), df1$movieId))[2:1])))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R possibility that uses `strsplit()` to split the column values, then `grepl()` to match them up in `vapply()`.  The trick here is to use `FUN.VALUE = integer(.)` in `vapply()` so that the `grepl()` result is magically converted to integer.

```
## split the 'category' column on '|'
s <- strsplit(df$category, "|", fixed = TRUE)
## run the unique sorted values through grepl(), getting integer result
newPart <- vapply(sort(unique(unlist(s))), grepl, integer(nrow(df)), df$category, fixed = TRUE)
## bind result to other columns
cbind(df[-3], newPart)
```

This results in the following data frame.

> ```
>   movieId                              title Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Drama Fantasy Romance Thriller
> 1       1                   Toy Story (1995)      0         0         1        1      1     0     0       0       0        0
> 2       2                     Jumanji (1995)      0         1         0        1      0     0     0       1       0        0
> 3       3            Grumpier Old Men (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       1        0
> 4       4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     1       0       0        0
> 5       5 Father of the Bride Part II (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       0        0
> 6       6                        Heat (1995)      1         0         0        0      0     1     0       0       0        1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A hadleyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)

max.categories = max(str_count(df1$category, "\\|")) + 1

df1new = df1 %>% separate(category, into=letters[1:max.categories], sep="\\|") %>%
  melt(c("movieId","title")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  dcast(movieId + title ~ value, fun.aggregate=length)
```

> ```
>   movieId                              title Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Drama Fantasy Romance Thriller
> 1       1                   Toy Story (1995)      0         0         1        1      1     0     0       0       0        0
> 2       2                     Jumanji (1995)      0         1         0        1      0     0     0       1       0        0
> 3       3            Grumpier Old Men (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       1        0
> 4       4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     1       0       0        0
> 5       5 Father of the Bride Part II (1995)      0         0         0        0      1     0     0       0       0        0
> 6       6                        Heat (1995)      1         0         0        0      0     1     0       0       0        1
> ```

`max.categories` is just a way to programmatically ensure that the `into` vector is at least as long as the maximum number of categories for a given `title`. If you already know this value is never greater than, say 5, then you can just do, for example, `into=letters[1:5]`.